# Installing modules with PyPM on ActiveState

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, activestate, pypm

I am new to python scripting and started to look into a script to allow me to SSH to a box and check it is still running.

I have installed ActiveState (Python 2.7) on my windows desktop. 
Using PyPM I have installed paramiko and pycrypto

but when I try to execute my scripts I get the following error:
Script: python C:\Python27\Scripts\RunOnEnv\ssh-matic.py

Error:ImportError:no Modules named ssh

When passing:
'>>>help('modules')

I can not see ssh in the list.

I have tried uninstalling and installing the modules with no problems.

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel really foolish.

After reading that paramiko has replaced ssh module there still is an ssh module available.

Ooops!!